# How can I get line breaks to work when using template literals in a prop?

Tags: reactjs, template-literals

How can I get line breaks to work when using template literals in a prop?

```
const TypographyGroup = ({label, content}) => (
  <div>
    <FadedLabel type='subheading'>
      {label}
    </FadedLabel>
    <Typography type='body1'>
      {content}
    </Typography>
  </div>
)

<TypographyGroup
  label='Address'
  content={`${profile.company.billingAddress.street_1}
    ${profile.company.billingAddress.street_2}
    ${profile.company.billingAddress.city}, ${profile.company.billingAddress.state} ${profile.company.billingAddress.zip}`}
/>
```

Here I'm hoping to have a line break after `street_1` and `street_2`, but am getting no line breaks at all.

Comment: You might be rendering `content` directly inside `<TypographyGroup>`. Might be better to pass content = {profile.company.billingAddress} as prop and add `<br/>` in the render method of  `<TypographyGroup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be rendering content directly inside `<TypographyGroup>`. Might be better to pass `content = {profile.company.billingAddress}` as prop and add `<br/>` in the render method of `<TypographyGroup>`

**Update**
So this might be what you want

```
const TypographyGroup = ({label, content}) => (
  <div>
    <FadedLabel type='subheading'>
      {label}
    </FadedLabel>
    <Typography type='body1'>
      {content.street_1}<br/>
      {content.street_1}<br/>
      {content.city} {content.state} {content.zip}
    </Typography>
  </div>
)

<TypographyGroup
  label='Address'
  content={profile.company.billingAddress}
/>
```

Comment: Updated so you can see how `content` is being rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I should have been more clear. `TypographyGroup` gets used for other data keys than just this address one. Is my only option to create a separate `TypograpghyGroup` for just address?

Comment: Does TypograpghyGroup group can get another component as it's content, or just text?

Comment: If you mean receiving props, yes, it is possible to pass components as props. But it might be better practice to pass data in as props from a parent and do the rendering inside the child component.

Comment: I went with creating a separate component for just the address. Thanks for your help.